# What to do if a variable was passed to putenv, then the memory was freed?

Tags: c, posix

what happens if call putenv() with an automatic variable as the argument, then return from the calling function while string is still part of the environment.

I read the documentation and it described this potential error and I was wondering what would happen. I'm interested in what will happen at the memory level and what will be located at the pointer.

Comment: same as any other dangling pointer

Comment: The behavior is undefined. Dereferencing an invalid pointer may or may not immediately break the program. What you will find at that location in memory is indeterminate.

Comment: @Anato, `putenv()` is not part of the standard C library.  "I read the documentation " --> What operating system and compiler are you using?

Comment: Assuming a stack-based implementation, the environment will continue to point to some location on the stack.  This variable is likely to become garbage when the stack is recycled.

Comment: If you call any function that makes use of the environment (e.g. `getenv()` and `execl()`) undefined behavior will result.

Comment: What to do *afterward* is the wrong question.  The thing to do is to avoid such a situation in the first place.

Comment: @ChrisDodd "the C standard has no concept of "an environment"." --> Hmmm, C spec use _environment_ (whole section on it) so it does use _environment_ as a concept.  "the C standard has no concept of ... getenv ..." is amiss as the standard library has `char *getenv(const char *name);`.  `putenv/getenv/setenv/unsetenv` are a part of many an OS, not only POSIX.  Trying to get OP to report more situation would be useful to improve the question.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, I'm working on Solaris, gcc compiler. Documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E86824_01/html/E54766/putenv-3c.html

Comment: @JohnBollinger, I study at the university and my teacher asked me this question, that’s why I’m asking.

Comment: If one of your instructors posed the question to you, then why are you asking *us*?  Possibly the question was meant to be rhetorical, but if not, then surely the idea was for *you* to think about it.  You gain little from just asking someone else.  And when you answer your teacher, do you plan to explain that you got it by asking someone else? Not doing so presents academic integrity concerns.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, I was looking for an answer and the only thing I found was that there would be a memory leak

Answer (score 3, accepted):

POSIX defines [`putenv()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/putenv.html) and says:

> The `putenv()` function shall make the value of the environment variable name equal to `value` by altering an existing variable or creating a new one. In either case, the string pointed to by `string` shall become part of the environment, so altering the string shall change the environment.

The pointer must remain valid (it cannot be an automatic string; it cannot be freed if it is allocated via `malloc()` et al) until it is replaced.  If you modify the string (e.g. because it is a local variable in a function that returns), when the storage space is reused, the environment will change in unpredictable ways.  There is no mechanism to delete an environment variable stored via `putenv()`; you can only overwrite it with a new, possibly empty, value.

The `putenv()` function was a legacy interface from at least 7th Edition Unix, if not earlier.  It is not the design one would use nowadays.  In fact, POSIX defines alternative functions that are better behaved:

- [`setenv()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setenv.html)
- [`unsetenv()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/unsetenv.html)

You should not use `putenv()` in new code.  It is advisable to use `setenv()` in place of `putenv()` if you update old code, but `setenv()` isn't a simple drop-in replacement for `putenv()`.